# C# Reading text or source code from tab in a browser - need an idea

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to make a small application that would read a title from current opened youtube video from my firefox or chrome browser and save it in .txt file on my computer.

I need an idea on how to accomplish this. Is it somehow possible to access tabs opened in firefox or chrome via c#?

Do you understand me? I want to somehow parse the data from browser from seleceted tab and save it into .txt file.

Would I have to use greasemonkey scripts for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tab is currently active then you could do this in C#:

```
string browser = "Firefox"; //or change to chrome/iexplore

var browserProc = Process.GetProcessesByName(browser)
                         .Where(b => b.MainWindowTitle.Contains("YouTube"))
                         .FirstOrDefault();

if (browserProc != null)
{
   string mainTitle = browserProc.MainWindowTitle;
}
```

You can then parse the relevant parts of `mainTitle` if you need to.

Comment: Very interesting! You mean if tab is active, which means opened in firefox, or selected?

The scenario I was thinking is: I open youtube playlist and music plays, and then my application just searches if there is youtube tab opened in firefox and saves the title of song in .txt. I am going to use this .txt file for xsplit or open broadcaster software for game streaming :D I will try this! Wow very nice idea man!

Comment: The browser doesn't have to be active (in can be in the background) but if there are more than one tabs open then the YouTube tab has to be the one that's open.

Comment: There is no `.Where()` extension for that method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Win32 API calls to do this. `FindWindowEx`, `GetWindowText`, etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919(v=vs.85).aspx